Handcrafting TCP Handshake
In order to experiment with tcp handshake, I want to handcraft one in a way such that I control sending each packet of the tcp handshake.
I tried it with scapy
>>>syn_packet = IP(dst="<dst_ip>")/TCP(dport=80, flags="S")
>>>send(syn_packet)

But the server responds with a syn-ack on its own.
Is there a way I can control when to send the syn-ack from the server ?
